# Removing Date within the Date Range

Tags: sql, date

Here is the sample data

[image]

How can I remove the date if the date is between the date range below?

The result should only display
**21 Jan 2015**

Comment: Doesn't the __IN__ work here in date?

Comment: nope, because there is there is a date range. I think this will not work using IN

Comment: So, you want to compare the date from the first table with the date range in the same row in the second table, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `between` to delete rows between the given dates :

```
DELETE FROM date1
WHERE        (date BETWEEN '01/26/2015' AND '01/27/2015')
```

Now values other than 21st Jan 2015 will get deleted :

use `select` query to view your result.

**Output :**`01/21/2015`

Comment: OFF: "OP needs final result as 21/1/2015.If delete that how come show ? :)"

Comment: if select we can view the same ..:)

Comment: You are right, but I do not understand you. I write the same answer like you. You comment that it is wrong, than you write this answer that you write for it is wrong... And finally you get an up vote and I do not. I think it is not too fair.

Comment: your first query : DELETE FROM table WHERE date = '2015-01-21' ..this will delete the date 21st Jan then how come output will be 21st..I have not deleted that also used another format i.e between..I have not forced anyone for upvote..i have just posted my view

Comment: Your first query is DELETE FROM... too. Another format... The result is the same. You have not forced anyone to upvote, just comment to an other answer (that do the same like yours) it is wrong.

Comment: that does not delete 21st Jan know

Answer (score 0):

Try this **format**:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date = '2015-01-21'
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date > '2015-01-20' AND date < '2015-01-22';
```

Maybe the date is not exactly '2015-01-21'.

Comment: OP needs final result as 21/1/2015.If delete that how come show ? :)

Comment: The question was not so clear, but I think the Delete is not bad answer, just i forgot the other table... The question was: "How can I remove the date..."

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display, use `NOT EXISTS()` in the select

```
SELECT Date FROM Dates d 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DateRange WHERE d.Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
```

If you need to delete the records

```
DELETE FROM Dates d 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DateRange WHERE d.Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE date BETWEEN '01/26/2015' AND '01/27/2015'
```